# Objective-C ternary operator resulting in @"null" or Boolean

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this line:

```
watchAgain == nil ? @"null" : (watchAgain ? 1 : 0)
```

`watchAgain` could be `nil`, `YES` or `NO`.

What's my best bet for either getting `@"null"`, `1` or `0` depending on the value?

At the moment I receive the error: `Incompatible operand types ('NSString *' and 'int')`

I'm new to Objective-C, so I'm guessing this might be quite a simple fix!

EDIT (context):

I have a toggle state in my iOS UI, so either YES or NO. However, I'd like to send a 3rd state to my Node.js backend of "they didn't select on or off", hence why I was thinking of sending a "null" string...

Comment: Forget the code you've already written. What are you trying to do? What is the action you are trying to perform? Also, what type is warchAgain? If it's a bool then it can only be YES or NO. Nil is not valid.

Comment: I have a toggle state in my iOS UI, so either `YES` or `NO`. However, I'd like to send a 3rd state to my Node.js backend of "they didn't select on or off", hence why I was thinking of sending a "null" string...

Comment: it makes no sense that you are returning either @"null" (which is a (very strange) NSString, or some sort of literal integer values of 1 or 0.

Comment: can you just log "watchAgain" value, so we can know what kind of object it is ? surely watchAgain is not an object type, remove * from it, then it should work.

Comment: It would be better to have an enum for this kind of thing.  From the looks of things I'd say you spent too much time in Javascript land.  In a lower level language like this (strongly-typed with pointers) then you need to make a distinction between pointers and primitives.

Comment: Hi Borrrden, Ben is a java expert, he's just having a toot around in iOS! :)

Comment: Is it possible in Java to have a variable that can either be a string or an integer? o,0  I really don't think it is, hence why I guessed Javascript.

Comment: the issue is totally and completely irrelevant.  he is generating **a piece of information to send to a server** to indicate one of three states.  you do that by using **three pre-agreed codes**, perhaps "902, 903, 904" or "blue" "green" "red" or whatever.  this is an absolute basic of the fundamental operations of computer communications!

Comment: @borrrden OP can confirm; JavaScript developer.

Answer (score -3):

For if you are setting button title

```
NSString *titleForButton = watchAgain == nil ? @"null" : (watchAgain ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

As far as i think you are trying to achieve is setting button title according to watchAgain variable, so the above titleForButton could be the title you would like to set.

What you were doing wrong in

```
watchAgain == nil ? @"null" : (watchAgain ? 1 : 0)
```

is assigning either string value or an integer value to a variable, so you should make it clear for compiler whether you are assigning a string or integer

Comment: (what a funny question this is!)  just FTR, channi. this is totally wrong.  it would set the button title to the characters "null" !!  anyway the question is unrelated to UIButton.

Comment: @channi, Even without the edit, WHERE did you see anything related to `UIButton`?! Why are there people that just assume something out of the blue for no damn reason?